# IIS 7 URL Rewrite or Reverse Proxy to Handle Firewall Security

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, firewall, reverse-proxy

I am setting up different web applications on a Win 2008 R2 server. I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. http://myserver/ should point to a local folder with static html pages
2. http://myserver/crm should "rewrite" to http://myserver:1234/ where I have installed a web based CRM application.

We have a change process to open firewall ports so instead of getting them to open the 1234 port, I would rather have people just go via http://myserver/crm and IIS should hide the port business behind scenes.

1. Do I need a reverse proxy in this case? Or a simple inbound rule?
2. At which website should I configure this rule?
3. Do I need to create a "CRM" virtual directory under default website?
4. Also, any rule example would help.
5. I hope this will accomplish the objective of not needing to open ports in firewall...?

Thanks
(Sorry if this is similar to another question, but I wasn't sure if I need a reverse proxy or a simple inbound rule.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You need inbound and outbound rule. The method to achieve this goal is called reverse proxy.
2. On the level of `Website` handling http://myserver/ domain or `Global` level.
3. No.
4. Use the rules below as a starting point.
5. I would say it's possible to achieve your goal using reverse proxy.

IIS Rewrite Rules:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="CrmInbound">
        <match url="^crm(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myserver:1234/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="CrmOutbound" preCondition="OnlyHtml">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="http://myserver:1234(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="http://myserver/crm(.*)" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="OnlyHtml">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think we are close. Getting internal server error though on both http://myserver/ and http://myserver/crm/. Will dig into tracing to see what's happening.

Comment: Ok, so I disabled the outbound piece and at least the internal server error is gone. I can see the main myserver site correctly and it navigates to myserver/crm but shows a blank page, both locally and on the network. Probably need to tweak the outbound somehow.

Comment: A small update: I tried applying a simple rule that rewrites myserver to myserver:1234, and it works fine. But I am trying to rewrite myserver/crm to myserver:1234 which is resulting in HTTP500 when I put in the outbound rule.

Comment: To sort of close this topic, as the issue is still unresolved, it seems that all I need is an inbound rule, not an outbound. So with an inbound rule, the next issue I am facing is that the page appears blank but no errors. I checked failed request logs and RequestURL is blank for child pages. I will now open another post in stackoverflow for this issue.